# Relationship between the variable on X-axis with the one on Y-axis

Tags: correlation, scatterplot, variable

I have two graphs here and I would like to know if there is a relationship between the variable on X-axis with the one on Y-axis of each of the graphs.

[image: Well level vs Pb content]
[image: Well level vs As content]

Comment: We don't do this for you so I'm guessing your question is "How can _I_ check for a relationship between these two variables?" - the first thing you'll need is the data behind these graphs, do you have that?

Comment: You can fit a regression line to the data in each case & test the null hypothesis that the slope is not statistically significantly different from 0.

Comment: Yes, I have the data behind these graphs. Do you need them ?

Comment: I've added the regression lines to the data in each case.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Regression line to "Well level vs Pb content"]

[image: Regression line to "Well level vs As content"]

Here are the regression lines to the data in each case.